# Made OSX .sh file into .app, refuses to execute

Tags: python, macos, sh

To preface, I've read other threads on the topic, but all their solutions don't work for me.

I have a small `.sh` file that just runs `python3 foo.py`. I used a [script](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) to turn this file into a `.app` file, but when I try to open it, I can see the app begin to appear in the dock and then disappear. However, when I open the file inside of the Unix executable itself in Terminal, all is well.

I have tried:

- Changing the shebang in the .sh file to both `#!/usr/bin` and `#!/urs/bin/env`
- Creating an empty `.plist` file
- Making sure every file has execute permissions

Oddly enough, running `open appname.app` gives the following:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/blah/blah/Lofi.app.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code into the question? You should also provide the code in your `.sh` script as well

Comment: The .sh script only holds a `python3` command. The rest of the Python code is quite long and I doubt it would be helpful to put that in there.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you've read other threads on the topic, and the solutions don't work, does that mean you tried every thing in the comments under the sh-to-app script? There are a couple of specific fixes enumerated there.

1. What OS are using? Looks like higher OS needs you to register the app with the OS.
2. Check permissions of your personal shell script
3. Does it open in Terminal with `open APP.app`? I think you're saying it does. You can look at the last comment under the the sh-to-app script for possibly helpful instructions.

Comment: Yes. I've tried changing `#!/usr/bin` to `#!/usr/bin/env` and adding a blank `Info.plist` file. I'm running MacOSX Sierra 10.12.6. All files in the .app have chmod +x permissions. Running `open` gives: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/blah/blah/Lofi.app.`

Comment: Okay. Can you put everything you have done into the question?

Comment: the error you say looks like a registration error, or you changed the name of the script. Or the script told the OS to register your app differently than you named it.

Comment: Yes, I've added that information, and no, I never changed the name of the script

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer, more of a workaround. I ended up taking the `APP.app/Contents/MacOS/APP` executable and creating an application in Automator that simply runs the file, and saving that process as an application in the `Applications` folder.